# If $\triangle {ABC} \sim \triangle {DEF}$, must $\angle {C} = \angle {F}$, or can any angle of $\triangle {DEF}$ be $\angle C$?

Tags: geometry, notation, definition, triangles, similitude

I am wondering if triangles $\triangle {ABC}$ and $\triangle {DEF}$ are similar, then this must mean that $\angle {C} = \angle {F}$, or does the order in which the letters of the triangle appear in the statement of their similarity have no bearing on which angles correspond to which in similar triangles?

A worksheet I am doing seems to imply that $\angle {C} = \angle {F}$ doesn't have to be the case here, but merely that one of the other angles of the triangle is equal to $\angle {C}$.

Comment: The letter order matters. You need to specify which vertices correspond to which for similarity to be well-defined.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no agreed convention on vertex ordering, when asserting that (for example) $~\triangle ABC~$ is similar to $~\triangle DEF.~$  Assuming that my understanding is correct, all that the assertion signifies is that the angles corresponding to the vertices $~a,b,c,~$ are equal to the angles corresponding to the vertices $~d,e,f,~$ **in some (as yet unspecified) order**.

Comment: usually yes. When dealing with books and more public and formal material, we respect the order of the points when writing a similarity. Of course it is not hard to check if the author is not caring about the order.

Comment: There is no universal agreement on that. Hence it's better to assume that vertices don't necessarily match in the order they are written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Convention/Notation Issue. The Author should indicate what that Notation is.

One **Common Convention** is $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle XYZ \tag{1}$ indicates $A \leftrightarrow X$ & $B \leftrightarrow Y$  $C \leftrightarrow Z$

PRO :
It is easy to Identify which sides are Proportional to which sides & which angles are equal to which angles.

CON :
It gives paradoxical cases like $\triangle ABC \not \sim \triangle YZX \tag{2}$ , even though Both (1) & (2) are talking about the Same 2 triangles !

The Other **Common Convention** is $T_1 = \triangle ABC \sim \triangle XYZ = T_2 \tag{3}$ indicates there is some way to match the the sides & angles , & that matching will be either given or has to be Derived later.

PRO :
(1) This allows writing $T_1 \sim T_2 \tag{4}$ , without worrying about the matching.
(2) More over , we can have Propositions like this : Given a triangle $P$ , we can make a new triangle $Q$ by joining the Mid-Points of the 3 sides which will be similar & have quarter Area. Here we do not even worry about matching the angles. Proving the Proposition will involve Deriving the matching Sides.
By Extension , we do not worry about matching the Sides in our Notations too.
(3) When we have multiple matchings , we still do not worry about it. Eq Isosceles triangles can be written like this $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle ACB \tag{5}$ & Equilateral triangles can have this $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle XYZ \sim \triangle YZX \sim \triangle ZYX \tag{6}$

**Summary : Both have PRO & CON : Author has to indicate the Notation used.**

OP Work-Sheet might be using the other Convention.

ADDENDUM :
There are other Conventions too.
When making the Drawing , the Author may mark the Points with Prime $'$ to indicate the Corresponding Points.
In that Notation , $T = \triangle ABC \sim \triangle A'B'C' = T' \tag{7}$
Of Course , when we have Isosceles triangle or Equilateral triangle , the Corresponding Points are not unique.
We might have something like this $T = \triangle ABC \sim \triangle A'B'C' \sim \triangle A'C'B' \sim \triangle B'C'A' = T' \tag{8}$ where we are reordering the Corresponding Sides of two Equilateral triangles.

Might be useful to mention that there is a Pictorial Convention too , where Corresponding lines are marked with tick marks like this :

[image: PICTORIAL SIMILARITY]

There are other Notational & Pictorial Conventions too.

Basically , the Author has to indicate which Convention & Notation is being used.